# Resource Path Location : Type R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, bluetooth

I was trying to build the Andriod application mentioned in the URL:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/bluetooth/bluetoothadapter/android-bluetooth-example/

But during build process I get error 'Type R cannot be resolved to a variable' - how cam I fix the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just import com.javacodegeeks.android.bluetoothtest.R or rebuild the project. Should work^^. Hope this helps.